# Count only original seconds with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a table with this structure and data, with start and stop positions of an audio/video. I have to count the original seconds and discard the not original ones.

E.g.

```
    CUSTOMER_ID ITEM_ID CHAPTER_ID  START_POSITION  END_POSITION
A   123456      1       6           0               97
B   123456      1       6           97              498
C   123456      1       6           498             678
D   123456      1       6           678             1332
E   123456      1       6           1180            1190
F   123456      1       6           1190            1206
G   123456      1       6           1364            1529
H   123456      1       6           1530            1531
```

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9qjQ.png)

Lines "E" and "F" does not represent original seconds because "D" line starts at 678 and finishes with 1332 so I need to create a new set of lines like this:

```
    CUSTOMER_ID ITEM_ID CHAPTER_ID  START_POSITION  END_POSITION
A   123456      1       6           0               97
B   123456      1       6           97              498
C   123456      1       6           498             678
D   123456      1       6           678             1332
E   123456      1       6           1364            1529
F   123456      1       6           1530            1531
```

[New Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH5oO.png)

Can you help mw with this?

Comment: It is rather unclear how you are deciding which values to use for the start and end positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  I am following you correctly, you can use `not exists` to filter out rows whose range is contained in the range of another row:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.customer_id = t.customer_id
        and t1.start_position < t.start_position 
        and t1.end_position   > t.end_position
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the self join as follows:

```
Select distinct t.* 
  from your_table t
  Left Join your_table tt
    On t.customer_id = tt.customer_id
   And t.item_id = tt.item_id
   And t.chapter_id = tt.chapter_id
   And t.rowid <> tt.rowid
   And t.start_position between tt.start_position and tt.end_position - 1
 Where tt.rowid is null
```